# Stash embeds containing multiple nested plugins doesn't retrieve anything

Tags: stash, embeds, variable

I'm trying to do some stash embeds but when embeds contain nested plugins (so, more than one) he doesn't retrive any value.

```
{my_loop}{stash:embed name="my_total{count}" file_name="_stash:total_htva_stash" stash:collection_name="acompte{count}" process="inline" parse_stage="set"}{/my_loop}
```

My embed stash template :

```
{exp:mx_calc expression="round(({exp:tally:total collection='{stash:collection_name}' decimals='2'}*0.21),2)" parse="inward"}{calc_result}{/exp:mx_calc}
```

If I just put 1 plugin in the embed :

```
{exp:tally:total collection='{stash:collection_name}' decimals='2'}
```

the embed retrieve a sum (tally plugin is made to sum some numbers) but when I put tally into mx calculator (to do a math on the tally's sum) it doesn't work. When I made it in EE embed it works but I need stash embed to use the result as a variable in the host template.

I don't know if it is clear (english is not my mother tongue).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `parse_depth="x"` to the Stash embed, where 'x' is a number greater than 4 (which is the default).

EDIT:

You are effectively using the embed like a snippet, so I would suggest including the embed before tag processing begins, without parsing it so that you can still pass it variables during:

```
{stash:embed name="my_total{count}" file_name="_stash:total_htva_stash" process="start" parse="no"}
```

Rather than `{stash:collection_name}` use `{acompte{count}}` in the embed.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks I tried it but it doesn't work...

Comment: Did my advice here help? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/11291

Comment: In fact I did everything you said in the devot-ee thread, so I replaced every EE embeds by stash embeds but still have problem to retrieve the right value of these embeds (because they contain nested plugins). I tried to add parse_depth parameter as you suggested but it doesn't work. I try to achieve my project but I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: Please see edit above